# how to update Linux Kernel on "Ubuntu LTS 20.04" Windows Subsystem for Linux 2

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, mdadm, initramfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

is it possible to update Linux kernel on WSL2 ukuu isn't possible and dpkg --install *.deb gives me an error

```
    (Reading database ... 68035 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) over (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-5.0.0-050000_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.0.0-050000 (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) over (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) over (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-5.0.0-050000-generic_5.0.0-050000.201903032031_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) over (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.0.0-050000 (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Setting up linux-modules-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.0.0-050000-generic (5.0.0-050000.201903032031) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-050000-generic
W: mkconf: MD subsystem is not loaded, thus I cannot scan for arrays.
W: mdadm: failed to auto-generate temporary mdadm.conf file.
```

[image]

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to upgrade the kernel on the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Regardless of what other versions of kernels you may have installed, WSL will boot only Microsoft's kernel.  Microsoft will ship appropriate updates to the kernel through their normal update procedures.

This is because Microsoft's kernel has drivers that the standard kernel does not have in order to enable features like file system integration and network sharing.  The standard Ubuntu kernels wouldn't have those features, and allowing them to boot would result in your WSL2 environment being very broken.

It's probably best to try to remove the kernel that you've installed and leave your WSL2 environment without an additional kernel.  You can do so either with `apt remove` or `dpkg -P`.

If you need a newer kernel or a specific kernel, or to do kernel development, you'll need to use an actual Linux installation, either in a VM or on physical hardware.